# Fancybox with images and youtube

Tags: jquery, youtube, fancybox

How to set fancybox with multitype objects?

I have this:

```
$("a.fancybox").attr('rel', 'gallery').fancybox({ 'type': 'swf' });
```

youtube works fine, but all images goes flash format.

When I remove type, images works fine, but youtube dont load. I figured out this.

If links are `$("a[href$=.jpg],a[href$=.png],a[href$=.gif]")` type image, else swf.

How to write this perfectly?

Answer (score 0):

remove the type attirbute...

```
$("a.fancybox").attr('rel', 'gallery').fancybox();
```

Do you have latest version of Fancybox?? Because fancybox understand a link flash, image or ajax bla bla... ok ;)